# Can't get the payload of a POST Request in Jersey

Tags: java, http, servlets, jakarta-ee, post

I need to recover the whole payload of a form POST request, to send it back to the receiver (PayPal requires this as a verification procedure). I tried several ways but I always get the same warning, with no payload:

```
Warning:   A servlet request to the URI http://localhost:8080/ipnlistener contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
```

Here's the code of the listener

```
@POST
@Path("/ipnlistener")
public Response testIpn(String t) {  
   System.out.println(t);
   return Response.ok().build();
}
```

I tried to add different `Consumes` annotations but nothing changes. Of course with `FormParam` annotations I'm able to retrieve single fields, but I really need the whole body of the request.

I also tried with the following

```
public Response testIpn(@Context HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {  
    BufferedReader reader= req.getReader();
    String sCurrentLine;
    while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }

   return Response.ok().build();
}
```

but I get the error

```
getInputStream() has already been called for this request
```

Comment: If you have resolve this issue please add the answer. I have got stuck and have no clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can add the following code to your file:

```
 @Context  
 private HttpServletRequest request;
```

The `HttpServletRequest` contains the whole body of the request!

Comment: I already tried to add it as an argument of the testIpn method, but it didn't work. When trying to get the buffered input from the object I got an error saying that the method had already been called somewhere else and cannot be called twice (sorry I  can't be more specific right now). Or you meant adding it outside the method signature? What's the difference? And what would you do to get the payload as a string?

Comment: @splinter123 did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same issue myself :(.